# R: select the IDs with 2 records (rows) in a certain domain

Tags: r, sorting, data-cleaning

```r
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)

date <- c('2018-06-29','2018-08-29','2018-08-29','2020-12-11','2020-12-12','2021-01-21','2021-12-21','2020-11-29','2019-07-12','2018-05-13','2021-06-08','2017-11-14','2018-07-15','2019-01-15','2020-02-19','2021-11-09')

domain <- c('condition','condition','procedure','condition','procedure','condition','condition','procedure','condition','procedure','procedure','procedure','condition','procedure','condition','procedure')

df <- cbind(ID, date, domain)
```

Example dateset:

```r
ID  date        domain
1   2018-06-29  condition
1   2018-08-29  condition
1   2018-08-29  procedure
2   2020-12-11  condition
2   2020-12-12  procedure
2   2021-01-21  condition
2   2021-12-21  condition
3   2020-11-29  procedure
4   2019-07-12  condition
4   2018-05-13  procedure
4   2021-06-08  procedure
5   2017-11-14  procedure
5   2018-07-15  condition
5   2019-01-15  procedure
5   2020-02-19  condition
5   2021-11-09  procedure
```

As you can see, some IDs are with one row in domain 'procedure', while others are with two or three rows in domain 'procedure'.
May I ask how to separate the IDs with different number of rows in domain 'procedure'?

Thank you!!

Comment: What do you mean by separate? What is your expected output?

Comment: @Maël Sorry that I did not make it clear. I mean the solution to select the IDs with different numbers of rows in 'procedure' and create the corresponding ID list. For example, IDs with one record in procedure, IDs with two records in procedure, IDs with three records in procedure.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `split` to split the 'ID' based on the number of 'procedure' elements in `domain` per 'ID' into a `list` of `vector`s

```
with(df, split(ID, ave(domain == "procedure", ID, FUN = sum)))
```

-output

```
$`1`
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3

$`2`
[1] 4 4 4

$`3`
[1] 5 5 5 5 5
```

---

If we want `unique` IDs

```
with(with(df, stack(tapply(domain == "procedure", ID, FUN = sum))), 
      split(as.character(ind), values))
```

#### Update

If we wanted the separate the data.frame into subset of data.frame based on the number of occurrence of 'procedure' for each 'ID', then `split` on the dataset instead of the column

```
 split(df, ave(domain == "procedure", ID, FUN = sum))
$`1`
  ID       date    domain
1  1 2018-06-29 condition
2  1 2018-08-29 condition
3  1 2018-08-29 procedure
4  2 2020-12-11 condition
5  2 2020-12-12 procedure
6  2 2021-01-21 condition
7  2 2021-12-21 condition
8  3 2020-11-29 procedure

$`2`
   ID       date    domain
9   4 2019-07-12 condition
10  4 2018-05-13 procedure
11  4 2021-06-08 procedure

$`3`
   ID       date    domain
12  5 2017-11-14 procedure
13  5 2018-07-15 condition
14  5 2019-01-15 procedure
15  5 2020-02-19 condition
16  5 2021-11-09 procedure
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID, date, domain)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am new to R, may I further ask how to create the corresponding dataframes for those IDs in different categories?

Comment: @KingAwake Do you want the subset of data.frames in a list.  I thought you wanted the IDs separated

Comment: @KingAwake I updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Comment: Thank you. You perfectly solved my question. Much appreciated!